# Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword when joining table to a select query

Tags: oracle

I am trying to link a table to a select query and I get the Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword.   This is the oracle sql I have written.

When I run things separately data pulls.   Its when I try to join them I get the error.  I tried adding in the Group BY and Order by per some help information I found on the Internet but still get the same error.

```
SELECT

AS_MASTER_NF.CONTRACT_NO
, AS_HISTORY_NF.AH_CONTRACT_NBR
, AS_MASTER_NF.ID
, AS_MASTER_NF.A_INVENT_DATE
, AS_MASTER_NF.A_DISP_DATE

FROM INFL_IDS.AS_MASTER_NF
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
               NVL(SUBSTR(ALTERNATE_ID, 0, INSTR(ALTERNATE_ID, '*')-1), ALTERNATE_ID) AS ASSET
              , AS_HISTORY_NF.AH_CONTRACT_NBR
               FROM INFL_IDS.AS_HISTORY_NF
               WHERE LENGTH (AH_CONTRACT_NBR)> 3) AS ASHISTORY
           ON INFL_IDS.AS_MASTER_NF.ID = INFL_IDS.ASHISTORY.ASSET

WHERE AS_MASTER_NF.A_INVENT_DATE IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY
AS_MASTER_NF.CONTRACT_NO
, AS_HISTORY_NF.AH_CONTRACT_NBR
, AS_MASTER_NF.ID
, AS_MASTER_NF.A_INVENT_DATE
, AS_MASTER_NF.A_DISP_DATE

ORDER BY
AS_MASTER_NF.CONTRACT_NO
, AS_HISTORY_NF.AH_CONTRACT_NBR
, AS_MASTER_NF.ID
, AS_MASTER_NF.A_INVENT_DATE
, AS_MASTER_NF.A_DISP_DATE

FETCH FIRST 20 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: have you tried `SQL> show err` to get complete list of errors ?

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
    ON INFL_IDS.AS_MASTER_NF.ID = INFL_IDS.ASHISTORY.ASSET
```

to:

```
    ON INFL_IDS.AS_MASTER_NF.ID = ASHISTORY.ASSET
```

Because, `ASHISTORY` is not a table or view under `INFL_IDS` schema but just a sub-query which's defined in this sql.